# Return the promise from sequential jQuery ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

This function makes two sequential AJAX calls, with data returned by page1 used in the request for page2.

```
function call() {
    return $.ajax("http://example.com/page1").done(function(d) { 
        $.ajax("http://example.com/page2", { data: d.foo });
    });
}
```

I'd like `call()` to return a promise that resolves only once `page2` has finished loading, rather than when `page1` has finished like it does at the moment, so it's possible to do this:

```
call().done(function() { console.log("page2 has loaded.") });
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Method chaining is best.

Comment: have you checked jquery deferred : http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call()` needs only very light modification.

Change `done` to `then` and return the inner `$.ajax()`.

```
function call() {
    return $.ajax("http://example.com/page1").then(function(d) {
        return $.ajax("http://example.com/page2", { data: d.foo });
    });
}
```